# AWS API Gateway and WAF limitation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am in a software development house, where we usually serve small to medium company.
As we move forward to bigger and bigger company where it is heavy compliance, we notice that there is a trend in requirement where this is part of the requirement.

1. All REST API and file upload **must** pass through **centralised** API gateway and WAF.
2. The upload file size limit (excel, pdf document)  is well above the API Gateway (10mb) and WAF 8kb size limitation

I don't know if this is something common out there.

But I don't see that API gateway and firewall is useful on this scenario as there is a hard limitation on it that I am force to not using these AWS services.

Kindly advice.

Comment: What question are you asking? Are you asking if it is common to see requirements documents which contain (1)? Are you asking if there is a way to have WAF scan more than the first 8kb of requests? Are you asking if it's possible to divide a file upload into several parts, each of which are 10mb or less so they fit through API Gateway?

Comment: @GregoryLedray Yes, I want to know it is common to see that requirement. I know that I can turn off the 8kb request, but would it expose to security issue?. Also, yes I would like to know if it's possible to divide a file upload into several parts, each of which are 10mb or less so they fit through API Gateway and at the same time did not go more than 30s limitation? I would like to still fit all these into AWS ecosystem if it's possible.

Comment: If your intention is to use native AWS services, then you may need to pursue flexibility on the requirement wrt file uploads. Investigate options for API requests through API Gateway/WAF but file uploads direct to CloudFront/S3 (using pre-signed URLs requested through API requests via APIG/WAF) and then have some additional compliance solution around ingestion of those uploads e.g. virus-scanning and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some questions / answers from your comment. These are my own opinions and based on my own experience.

> I know that I can turn off the 8kb request, but would it expose to security issue?

Yes. WAF won't prevent the security vulnerabilities it is designed to prevent when requests are larger than 8kb and the compromising part of the request is not in the first 8kb. I believe it is possible to circumvent WAF by "padding" the front of a request. For example, "padding" the front of a SQL injection attack (which would normally be blocked by WAF) with 8kb of no-op whitespace.

> Also, yes I would like to know if it's possible to divide a file upload into several parts, each of which are 10mb or less so they fit through API Gateway and at the same time did not go more than 30s limitation?

You could, hypothetically, split arbitrary binary files into 9.9 MB chunks and send those chunks in separate HTTP requests over the network to something like a Lambda which is behind API Gateway and have Lambda deposit these chunks into a S3 bucket. Whenever you deposit a "chunk" the Lambda could check if you have received and stored all of the expected "chunks" in S3 already. If you have received all of the expected "chunks" then the Lambda could concatenate the chunks and put them into whatever file storage (presumably a separate S3 bucket) you want to use, and then delete the "chunks" in the original S3 bucket.

Seems pretty stupid to go to all of that trouble but it's possible. Here is an AWS recommended way to upload files to S3 without going through API Gateway: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/allowing-external-users-to-securely-and-directly-upload-files-to-amazon-s3/

Comment: It's AWS recommended way, but the requirement and compliance is that all file upload must pass through centeralised WAF and API gateway.